# HTML validation error: Element <div> not allowed as child of element <ul> in this context

Tags: css, html, validation, html-lists

This error is part of my nav bar (below):

```
<nav>
<ul>
    <div class="vr"></div>
    <li><a href="index.html" >Welcome</a></li>
    <div class="vr"></div>
    <li><a href="services.html" >Services</a></li>
    <div class="vr"></div>
    <li><a href="guestbook.html">Guestbook</a></li>
    <div class="vr"></div>
    <li><a href="locations.html" >Locations</a></li>
    <div class="vr"></div>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    <div class="vr"></div>
</ul>
```

And is styled with (below):

```
nav {
padding-top: 5px;
padding-bottom: 5px;
margin-bottom: 20px;
background-color: rgba(7, 7, 8, 0.85);
border: 1px solid white;}

ul {
list-style-type: none;
position: relative;
right: 10px;}

li {
display:inline-block;
width: 19%;
margin:auto;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.2em;}

a{
color: white;
font-size: 1.2em;
text-decoration: none;}

.vr{
display: inline-block;
width: 1px;
background-color: white;
height: 20px;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
top: 1px;}
```

Which creates a vertical line effect between each nav item.

Note: I tried to post a picture of the navbar effect but as this is my first post I don't have enough reputation, but I will email to anyone if you can help

My question is does anyone know how to replicate this without causing the validation error?

> Element `<div>` not allowed as child of element `<ul>` in this context.

Comment: You can't stick anything but `li` within `ul`. Simple as that.

Comment: A 'ul' is an unordered list.  you should only have 'li' elements (list items) and child elements.  You can place the 'div' as a child to the 'li'

Comment: Yeah, exactly, instead you could use http://jsfiddle.net/cYxvw/

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could just axe the extra markup and place the .vr line styles directly on 
the `<li>` like so

```
li {
    border-left: 1px solid white;
}
```

@ http://jsfiddle.net/cYxvw/

Comment: Or maybe stash it in with the pseudo class :before on the '<li>'

Answer (score 0):

Place the  inside the list elements like so:

```
<ul>

<li><div class="vr"><a href="index.html" >Welcome</a></div></li>

<li><div class="vr"><a href="services.html" >Services</a></div></li>

<li><div class="vr"><a href="guestbook.html">Guestbook</a></div></li>

<li><div class="vr"><a href="locations.html" >Locations</a></div></li>

<li><div class="vr"><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></div></li>

</ul>
```